# A grammar challenge

Tags: grammar, parsing, newspaper-grammar

This sentence is too complex for my modest reading abilities. AI translations seem to be challenged, too. Can someone explain how this part works grammatically?

などモラルに欠【か】ける例【れい】もあり

男性【だんせい】が女性【じょせい】の体【からだ】をジロジロ見【み】るなどモラルに欠【か】ける例【れい】もあり、敬遠【けいえん】につながった

*•  Men have ogled women's bodies, which is not in line with their morals and has led to their reticence.*

*•  There were also instances of lack of morals, such as men ogling women's bodies, which led to a lack of respect.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/national/20220216-OYT1T50205

Perhaps there is a clue in these different readings?

例【れい】 custom; practice

例【ためし】 precedent; example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [男性が女性の体をジロジロ見るなどモラルに欠ける]例もあり
> There are also practices of []

What kind of practices?

> 男性が[女性の体をジロジロ見るなど]モラルに欠ける
> Men lacking in [] morals

What kind of morals?

> 女性の体をジロジロ見るなど
> such as staring at women's bodies

In total:

> 男性が女性の体をジロジロ見るなどモラルに欠ける例もあり
> There are also practices of men lacking in morals such as staring at women's bodies.

Comment:  Once AI translations give me the gist, I can usually guess the details, but this sentence was a bit trickier. Thanks!